# "DFT". Understanding the formula $e^{-i2\pi k}$ $k$ is a real number

Tags: fft, dft

I am studying about fast Fourier transform.

Assuming that $x_0$, $x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}$ are complex numbers, the DFT is defined as follows.

$$f_j = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x_k e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{n}jk},\quad j= 0,\ldots, n-1$$

In the definition, $$W = e^{-i2 \pi/n}$$ and reorganize it,

$$f_j = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} x_k W^{jk},\quad j= 0,\ldots, n-1.$$

At this time, I looked at the equation below and solved $W$

$$
\begin{align}
W(j) &= e^{-2 * pi * i * j / n}\\
      &= e^{ (\pi \cdot i) \cdot (-2 \cdot j / n)}\\
      &= \left(e^{\pi \cdot i}\right)^{-2 \cdot j / n}
& \text {and } {e^{\pi \cdot i}= -1 }\\
&\text{so}\\
      &= (-1)^{-2 \cdot j / n}\\
      &= \left( -1^{-2} \right)^{j / n}\\
      &= 1^{j / n}\\
      &= 1
\end{align}$$

I couldn't figure out where was wrong by solving the equation.
Help me out on what part I did wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$e^{ (\pi \cdot i) \cdot (-2 \cdot j / n)}
      \color{red}{\ne} \left(e^{\pi \cdot i}\right)^{-2 \cdot j / n}$$

You can't just $e^{a\cdot b}= \left(e^a\right)^b$ for arbitrary complex $a,b$, because $e^a$ [is not necessarily a positive real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Complex_exponents_with_a_positive_real_base)
.

Answer (score 4):

Please recognise $N$-th [root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) (on the complex-plane):

$$ 1^{1/N} = e^{j \frac{2\pi}{N} k} ~~,~~ k = 0,1,...,N-1 $$

where $j$ is the imaginary unit in DSP notation. Hence $1^{1/N} = 1$ is true but incomplete, for you ignore the complex roots.

So in your derivation last two lines should follow as:

$$ 1^{m / N} = (1^{1/N})^m $$
$$ e^{j\frac{2\pi}{N} k m } $$

where $j$ is the imaginary unit and $k$ is an integer. (I've replaced $n$ with $N$ and $j$ with $m$ for consistency of notation)